# use SQLcl with EZconnect and multiple hostnames (ADDRESS_LIST=)

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, tnsnames, exadata, oracle-sqlcl

this is our classic `tnsnames.ora`

```
test1=
(DESCRIPTION=
    (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=4)
    (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)
    (ENABLE=BROKEN)
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example1.example.com)(PORT=1521))
        (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example2.example.com)(PORT=1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME=EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE.DBS)
    )
)
```

I use this SQLcl command:

```
sql -nohistory -noupdates -S $username/$password@$hostname:$port/$servicename @$filename
```

How to specifiy multiple hostnames? Not only one? It's some kind of active passive cluster (Exadata).

*Edit after first answer:*

I added in shell script (in this dir `tnsnames.ora`):

```
TNS_ADMIN=/example/example
```

I call `$sqlcl -nohistory -noupdates -S $username/$password@"MY-DB" @$filename` and get back the error:

```
./script.sh
  USER          = MY_USER
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY-DB
  Error Message = IO Error: Unknown host specified
  USER          = MY_USER
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@MY-DB:1521/MY-DB
  Error Message = IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EZconnect was not meant for things like that.

SQLcl can use `tnsnames.ora` as well. Just create one and use it:

```
sql -nohistory -noupdates -S $username/$password@test1 ...
```

Or you can do this, if you really want to provide all that stuff as a commandline argument:

```
sql -nohistory -noupdates -S $username/$password@"(DESCRIPTION= (CONNECT_TIMEOUT=4) (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3) (ENABLE=BROKEN) (ADDRESS_LIST= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example1.example.com)(PORT=1521)) (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=example2.example.com)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVER=DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE.DBS)))" ...
```

Using tnsnames.ora:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ export JAVA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/jdk
[oracle@o71 ~]$ export PATH=/home/oracle/sqlcl/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
[oracle@o71 ~]$ export TNS_ADMIN=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
MIN19=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.71)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME =  min19_o71)
    )
  )

[oracle@o71 ~]$ sql bp/bp@min19

SQLcl: Release 18.4 Production on Tue Mar 26 09:28:11 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Mar 26 2019 09:28:12 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.2.0.0.0


SQL>
```

Comment: @Ivanov see my edit. It does work with tnsnames.ora.